# Not able to start kafka with .\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties cmd

Tags: apache-kafka, wmic

I have preconfigured zookeeper and kafka using the following link used follow link : https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os
After making all the changes, I execute this command in cmd prompt :

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

but the following error is thrown :

```
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: wmic is in the System32 folder (C:\windows\system32\wbem) . Can you check if it is added to your PATH variable?  `PATH=C:\Windows\System32\wbem;etc...`

Comment: Yes its already added but still didn't worked.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue. I added `C:\Windows\System32\wbem` to path.

Now I am not getting the same error but no logs are getting printed after starting kafka-server.

[Kafka server not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524750/kafka-server-not-returning-anything?noredirect=1#comment78010565_45524750)

Answer (score 1):

This is because WMIC internally runs other OS commands. For this C:\Windows\System32 must be set in Classpath. If this is missing, nothing gets displayed when starting Kafka server.

Answer (score 1):

go to System environment variables form control panel, edit PATH and append below to existing path value separated by ;

C:\Windows\System32\wbem;%PATH%;

after setting PATH in env variables, confirm whether wmic is picked properly:

> open command prompt and type below command

where wmic

This should return the following as output:

"C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe"