# Kafka server not returning anything

Tags: apache-kafka

Zookeper is up and running in windows env.Now when i start Kafka server using

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

nothing is displayed

```
G:\Apache Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>.\bin\windows\kafka-serv
er-start.bat .\config\server.properties

G:\Apache Kafka\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0>
```

I am following [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1068998/Running-Apache-Kafka-on-Windows-without-Cygwin) article.

Comment: Is the space in "kafka-serv<space>er-start.bat" a typo in your question or an error in you command line?

Comment: it has appeared because of copy pasting from cmd

Answer (score 3):

The issue resolved after including 
C:\Windows\System32 in PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the path:

```
 %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\;SystemRoot%
```

in **User** %PATH% Environment variable, and not in **system** %PATH% Environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer It's worked for me after doing lot of search..

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the existing Kafka folder and un-tarring the downloaded Kafka{version}.tgz file worked for me.

> **Caveat:** Although this is not an ideal solution but it works for individuals
>   learning/exploring Kafka wanting to just get the things done.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the %SystemRoot%\system32 variable to path. Then restart zookeeper and kafka-server. Then it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

yesi resolved this issue goton system variable settings and the edit path
and click new  after you paste this  C:\Windows\System32 in you path
then close cmd and again open new cmd and try that it's  works for me

Answer (score 0):

For Widows Operating System 64 :
Steps :
Find the Wbem software path in your c drive / windows folder
Exmple :
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

And
set in the  system environment path variable.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as well, basically we are adding the location of cmd terminal(you see it on the title of the terminal) to path variable

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that I tried to start kafka server, there was no error but the logs were also not printed i.e. no response from server.

I added paths below in path name "path" both in user and system variable just didn't work for me.

C:\Windows\System32\wbem;%PATH%;

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem

C:\Windows\System32\wbem

But doing as below worked perfectly for me:

%SystemRoot%\system32

Add this path in variable name "path" in system variable.
And,

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem

Add this to user variable's "path".

Thanks to one of the comment from Priyanka Thakur.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I simply have to locate and add wbem location under "user variables" >> Path on Windows. It is usually present at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem.

Screenshot attached.[kafka_start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ3KE.png)