# Kafka does not start blank output

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Im workign to install Kafa and Zookeeper.

I have already run the Zookeeper and it is currently running.
I set up everything as in [https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os]

when i finally run in my cmd,

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

there is no output, it just moves shows the next command line started.
[image: Kafka does not start with no errors]
Please help me out.

Comment: there is not any issue , You can check the logs to view the complete details

Comment: @RohitYadav, There is no logs created, the Kafka does not show any sign of start., please check out the image ive added to the question.

Comment: Please share server.properties file...probably some config error which leads to this..

Comment: i faced an issue with find the debuging logs in kafka, i'm pretty sure you need to create `logs` folder inside the `kafka` folder and then run it, after doing it update your question with those logs

Comment: @Reznik, the logs folder had to be manually created. Once i did that i used `kafka-server-start.bat D:\Kafka\kafka\config\server.properties' to run the Kafka service and it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

1. Create the logs folder and mention it on the sever.properties, it will not create the folder automatically.
2. go to your cmd and run `kafka-server-start.bat D:\<pathofkafka>\config\server.properties`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find someone with with the same issue I had! Zookeeper running, but kafka not doing anything at all except returning to the next line with no log, error, or anything. Dunno if the cause is the same, but the solution for me, oddly enough, was to download and open cygwin, and run the command exactly as you have it, except with flipping all the \s to /s and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

After lot of search this is  the way I solved
You have to add in **User path in Environment Variable**:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\;SystemRoot%
```

In **User %PATH% Environment variable, and not in system %PATH% Environment variable**.
this question already replied on this page:
[Kafka server not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45524750/kafka-server-not-returning-anything)